# RabbitMQ Management console not working

Tags: rabbitmq

I have started with RabbitMQ. I have a (windows) machine on which I installed two RabbitMQ nodes as a service - I have choose the nodename, port and service name for each of them. The services are running normally (i see that they are listening in a netstat-a).

I have also installed management plugin with "rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management" and restarted both services. But the plugin isn't running - I dont see it listening in a netstat and I can't connect to the management console via browser.

Any idea what could be wrong? Is there any log to see what is goind on?

**Updated**: when I do rabbitmq-plugins list i get:

```
c:\RabbitMq\sbin>rabbitmq-plugins list
[e] amqp_client                       3.0.1
[ ] cowboy                            0.5.0-rmq3.0.1-git4b93c2d
[ ] eldap                             3.0.1-gite309de4
[e] mochiweb                          2.3.1-rmq3.0.1-gitd541e9a
[ ] rabbitmq_auth_backend_ldap        3.0.1
[ ] rabbitmq_auth_mechanism_ssl       3.0.1
[ ] rabbitmq_consistent_hash_exchange 3.0.1
[ ] rabbitmq_federation               3.0.1
[ ] rabbitmq_federation_management    3.0.1
[ ] rabbitmq_jsonrpc                  3.0.1
[ ] rabbitmq_jsonrpc_channel          3.0.1
[ ] rabbitmq_jsonrpc_channel_examples 3.0.1
[E] rabbitmq_management               3.0.1
[e] rabbitmq_management_agent         3.0.1
[ ] rabbitmq_management_visualiser    3.0.1
[e] rabbitmq_mochiweb                 3.0.1
[ ] rabbitmq_mqtt                     3.0.1
[ ] rabbitmq_old_federation           3.0.1
[ ] rabbitmq_shovel                   3.0.1
[ ] rabbitmq_shovel_management        3.0.1
[ ] rabbitmq_stomp                    3.0.1
[ ] rabbitmq_tracing                  3.0.1
[ ] rabbitmq_web_stomp                3.0.1
[ ] rabbitmq_web_stomp_examples       3.0.1
[ ] rfc4627_jsonrpc                   3.0.1-git7ab174b
[ ] sockjs                            0.3.3-rmq3.0.1-git92d4ba4
[e] webmachine                        1.9.1-rmq3.0.1-git52e62bc
```

Comment: What do you get when you do a `rabbitmq-plugins list`?

Comment: dtryon: I have updated the question with the list I get.

Comment: Having exactly the same problem.

Comment: @Fopedush see my answer below.

Comment: i have the same problem on vrabbitmq-server-3.8.3

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of other people with the same problem: In my case, this solved my issue:

Sometimes, on Windows, it's not enough to do just `rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management`. UI is accessible **only after reinstalling RabbitMQ**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51879608/421642

Answer (score 1):

I have also posted this questions on the RabbitMq mailing list. One nice guy from the rabbitmq answred:

> Ah, I think I see the problem. Setting RABBITMQ_SERVICENAME for your
>   services sets RABBITMQ_BASE, which then controls the location of where
>   the RabbitMQ service(s) will look for the enabled_plugins file.
>
> But you are not setting this when invoking rabbitmq-plugins.bat, so
>   it's writing the file to a different location. And sadly there's a bug
>   in the rabbitmq-plugins.bat script which prevents it from looking at
>   RABBITMQ_SERVICENAME.
>
> I'll file a bug to get that fixed. But in the mean time you should be
>   able to get the management plugin started by copying the
>   enabled_plugins file from %APPDATA%\RabbitMQ\enabled_plugins to
>   %APPDATA%\TermaniaDevRabbitMQ\enabled_pluagins and
>   %APPDATA%\TermaniaProdRabbitMQ\enabled_plugins.
>
> Since you're using RabbitMQ 3.x you do not need to reinstall the
>   service, just restart it.
>
> Cheers, Simon

That helped me.