# RabbitMQ management console not accessible on Windows Server 2016 http://localhost:15672/

Tags: rabbitmq

I have finished installing RabbitMQ on Windows Server 2016, and service is running and plugins are installed however i cannot access the RabbitMQ Management Console. Can someone please assist on what could be the cause?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RabbitMQ Management console not working](https://serverfault.com/questions/475200/rabbitmq-management-console-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled web management plugin for RabbitMQ?

Also you can check this question if you encounter any problems related to enabling management plugin - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43464521/run-rabbitmq-plugins-enable-rabbitmq-management-failed

Comment: rabbitmq-plugins installed successefully, i am running the Windows Server  2016 Virtual machine on a Windows Hyper V